# Django REST Framework doesn't render ModelViewSet with GM2MField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST Framework and django-gm2m application:

**models.py**

```
class DocIncome(models.Model):
    doc_date = models.DateTimeField()
    doc_num = models.IntegerField(unique_for_date='doc_date')
    follower = GM2MField()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class DocIncomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.DocIncome
        exclude = ()
```

**views.py**

```
class DocIncomeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.DocIncomeSerializer
    queryset = DocIncome.objects.all()
```

But i open api url I get the error -

> Exception Value: 'GM2MField' object has no attribute 'get_limit_choices_to'
>
> Exception Location:   C:\Users\konyshev.na\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\field_mapping.py in get_relation_kwargs, line 252

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using `django-gm2m`. Then please Specify It - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes I use django-gm2m, thanks for remarks.

Comment: How you used `get_limit_choices_to` anywhere in project. Or might be bug of library

Comment: I don't use it specially

Comment: Then it is the error of library - previously i used some different library and it gave me error. By the way why are you using `django-gm2m`

Comment: I have several models DocIncome, DocWriteoff, DocMove. And each instance of each model can have link to other instances of other models. That's why I decided to use django-gm2m.